# Extension 'ESLint' cannot format '../../../file.tsx'. How to debug this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript-eslint, prettier-eslint

I started a project 3 months ago and since a while my ESLint formatter suddenly stopped working (like 1 week ago). Can't get it to work in any way. I didn't do any package updates. It could be that I have updated the ESLint extension itself and the global yarn version.

The formatter I am using in **VSCode** is:

```
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  },
```

I have tried cleaning my Yarn packages and reinstalling them. I have tried several other ESLint settings but can't get it to work.

This issue occurs in two different projects, so I'm guessing it has to do with the extension itself. In one of my project I am getting this message as well:
[image]

When I click it and select a node path, it doesn't do anything unfortunately. Also when I switch to a completely different laptop, I still get the issue. So It probably has to do with my preferred configuration + the updated extension.

**I can't seem to find a good way to debug this, and it's rather trial and error right now. Could you help me with some next steps on how to discover the problem and how to get closer to a more focused question?**

[image]

*Note:
If you need any more info, please let me know and I'll update asap.*

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.